# Custom number sequence formatting

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sequence, number-formatting

The system I am working with has a numbering system where the numbers `0-999` are represented by the usual `0-999`, but `1000` is represented by `A00`, followed by `A01`, `A02`, `A03`, etc, `1100` being `B00` etc.

I can't think of a way to handle this in T-SQL without resorting to inspecting individual digits with huge case statements, and there must be a better way than that. I had thought about using Hexadecimal but that's not right.

```
DECLARE @startint int = 1,
        @endint int = 9999;

;WITH numbers(num)
AS
(
    SELECT @startint AS num
    UNION ALL SELECT num+1 FROM numbers
    WHERE num+1 <= @endint
)
SELECT num, convert(varbinary(8), num) FROM [numbers] N
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

With this `999` is now `3E7`, where it should just be `999`.

This currently produces this:

```
Number    Sequence
0         0x00000000
1         0x00000001
...
10        0x0000000A
...
100       0x00000064
...
999       0x000003E7
1000      0x000003E8
```

What I'm looking for:

```
Number    Sequence
0         000
1         001
...
10        010
11        011
12        012
...
999       999
1000      A00
1001      A01
...
1099      A99
1100      B00
1101      B01
1200      C00
```

I need this to work in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Can you please show your expected output and current data

Comment: SQL Server already has [Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx). This recursive version is actually one of the slowest ways to generate a numbers table, not a way to generate the next number in a sequence. Finally, your problem isn't one of rollover (you don't roll over at all), it's a matter of formatting a number to a string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not worried about how fast or slow it is. The system was written when people were new to code so there's actually a table that stores all of this... *cringe*... but that does mean I get to insert it and never worry about it again.

Comment: I also had a look at sequences but they require server 2012 :(

Comment: You are *still* using the wrong algorithm. In fact, a simple `IDENTITY` column would be enough as long as you got the formatting part right

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's what I'm trying to ask in the question. How do I format it? I'm well aware of `IDENTITY` and your answers would be helpful if I was designing a new table, but I'm not. The script I provided is a SSCCE I made to quickly generate numbers and test formatting ideas I have, which is where I am stuck.

Comment: @Logan then change the title and text to reflect this. A good title and text are essential if you want an answer. Also, does this numbering scheme have a name? What is the value range and what happens with eg 2100 ?

Comment: You could perform integer division to split the number, eg `CHAR((@i/1000) +64) ` will return `A` for 1000 and `cast( @i %1000 as nvarchar(3))` will return the remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use integer division and modulo to separate the hundreds part from the tens. 
After that, you can add 64 to the quotient to get an ASCII value starting from `A`.

```
create function function dbo.fn_NumToThreeLetters(@num integer)
RETURNS nchar(3)
AS
begin
RETURN (SELECT (case 
                    when @num/1000 >0 then 
                        CHAR(( (@num-900)/100) +64) 
                        + replace(cast( @num %100 as nchar(2)),' ','0')
                    else cast(@num as nvarchar(3))
                end) 
       )
END

select dbo.fn_NumToThreeLetters(1100)
-------
B00

select dbo.fn_NumToThreeLetters(999)
-------
999
```

The first `when` clause ensures that the conversion is applied only if a number is above 1000. If it is, subtract 900 then divide by 100, so we get a number that starts from 1 for 1000, 2 for 1100, etc.

Add 64 to it to get an ASCII starting from A and convert it back to a character with `CHAR`.

The remainder just needs to be converted to a 2-digit nchar, where spaces are replaced with `0`.

This will work only up to 3500. The question doesn't specify what should be done with larger numbers

Comment: Spec only specifies values up to `Y99`, so this works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: select  dbo.fn_NumToThreeLetters(1010 )
select  dbo.fn_NumToThreeLetters(1001 )   These two numbers will give same result "A10"